# How to exec bash script w/o exiting shell

Tags: bash, shell, exec

I want to execute a bash script in the current shell, not a subshell/subprocess. I believe using `exec` allows you to do that.
But if I run:

```
exec ./my_script.sh
```

the shell will exit and it will say "process completed". Is there a way to execute a script in the same shell somehow w/o exiting the process.

note the only thing my_script.sh does is:

```
export foo=bar
```

but if there was some error in my script, it didn't appear in the console.

Comment: What you are actually trying to do is called "sourcing" not "execing".  Execing means overwriting the current process (i.e. the shell) so that it is running a different executable.

Comment: See: `help source` or `help .`

Answer (score 2):

As @Snakienn has said, you can / should use the "." builtin command to "source" the file containing commands; e.g.

```
 . ./my_script.sh
```

What this does is to *temporarily* change where the shell is reading commands from.  Commands and other shell input are read from the file as if they were being read from the terminal.  When the shell gets to the end-of-file, it switches back to taking input from the console.

This is called "sourcing". (Not "execing".)   And indeed the shell accepts `source` as an alternative name for the `.` command.

The `exec` command does something completely different.  As the `bash` manual entry says:

> ```
>  exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> If command is specified, it **replaces** the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.

The concept and terminology of `exec` comes from early UNIX (i.e Unix V6 or earlier) where the syscalls for running a child command were `fork` and `exec`.  The procedure was:

- `fork` the current process creating a clone of current process (the child)
- in the child process `exec` the new command
- in the parent process, wait for the child process to complete

Comment: How does this effect echo $BASH_SUBSHELL and (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)

Comment: Sourcing does not create a subshell.  (Try it it for yourself!!)

Comment: echo $BASH_SUBSHELL  (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)  user@60053:~# . ./new.sh 
0 1 it appears it started a subshell for the parenthesis.

Comment: Yes ... because `(` `)` creates a subshell.  But that is eactly the same as if you typed that command line at the command prompt.  The source command has nothing to do with it.  But ... hey ... there are tutorials, manual entries, books and even formal specification documents that describe / explain this.   You shouldn't need to ask me this, in a comment on an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `. ./my_script.sh`.

The first dot stands for the current shell.

Comment: Not exactly.  The "." is a builtin command that means "read commands from the file and execute them in the current shell.  (In 'csh' the builtin command for doing this is called 'source'.)

Answer (score 0):

man page says:-

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
>         If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new  process
>         is  created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.  If
>         the -l option is supplied,  the  shell  places  a  dash  at  the
>         beginning  of  the  zeroth  argument passed to command.This is
>         what login(1) does.  The -c option causes command to be executed
>         with  an empty environment.

if you want to execute a bash script in the current shell,you can try

> bash my_script.sh or ./my_script.sh